# Get a script to work on a specific sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi everyone and thanks in advance,

I have a script which I want to set up on a monthly timing trigger to copy column B on a specific sheet in a Google Spreadsheet. Below is the script but it only works on on the sheet that is open at the time. What do I need to add please to get it to work on the first sheet in the worksheet only please?

```
function UpdateSummary() {
var sheet =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); //define spreadsheet name
var column = sheet.getRange("O1").getValue();
var row = 2;
Utilities.sleep(100000);  // Slowdown the script (10 second)
var UpdateSummary = sheet.getRange("B2:B205"); // Select and copy the column
UpdateSummary.copyValuesToRange(sheet, column+3, column+3, row, row+205); // Paste the data
sheet.getRange(1, column+3).setValue(new Date()); // add date in column title
sheet.getRange("O1").setValue(column+1);  // Incremente variable
}
```

Thank you,

John

Answer (score 0):

```
var sheet =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); //define spreadsheet name
```

With this kind of error it means that the function being called is not the function that you want. Either the whole function is incorrect or look at the getActiveSheet() function and edit it to include sheets that your not currently in.

Comment: Hi Luke Rixon, the function seems to work fine when I tested it however I noticed if I have a different sheet (not the "Summary" sheet which is the one with the column to be copied) open the function performs the 'column copy and paste' on this sheet and not my desired "Summaery" sheet. I am a bit stumped at this point and any help would be amazing. Thank you, John

Comment: I will add another answer with an example code that you can edit to your preferences.

Comment: Thanks Luke, that would be fantastic! John

Comment: it's up now, sorry it took a while.

Comment: Thanks Luke, I will go and try it now. Thanks again. John

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet 1');   
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()  
  var maxRows = sheet.getLastRow()
  var datatoCopy = []   
  for( var row = values.length -1; row >= 0; --row ){
    if (values[row][5] == 'here'){
     var whereToCopy = row
     Logger.log(whereToCopy);
     break
     }
     }
   for(row=whereToCopy-1;row<maxRows-1;++row){
    var rowData=[]
    rowData.push(values[row+1][2]+'*C*');// I added these 'indicators' to show what happens... delete them when the result is ok ;-)
    rowData.push(values[row+1][3]+'*D*');//
    rowData.push(values[row+1][4]+'*E*');//
    datatoCopy.push(rowData);// store column data in an array - remove the ** that I used to see what was copied ;-)
    }
    Logger.log(datatoCopy)
sheet.getRange(whereToCopy, 3, datatoCopy.length, datatoCopy[0].length).setValues(datatoCopy);// overwrite data to column E
}`enter code here`
```